# Facebook search api

Tags: api, facebook

Is it possible to get user's data such as "relationship_status", "interested_in", "political" etc. because all I'm getting is just basic info: id, name, last_name, gender, locale...
Or maybe this isn't possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to request extended permissions to access those fields.

[List of available permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

Comment: As I understand in order to get this information user has to make his/her details public OR I need him to login. So can't I do this without user logging-in?

Comment: @bah without a user giving you permissions - no. But if a user gave you permissions once + you requested `offline_access` permission then you can access this info any time without user being currently logged in to your app.